# Can't get Certificates with Let's Encrypt for Roundcube/Apache Configuration

Tags: debian, virtualhost, apache2, lets-encrypt, roundcube

So everytime i try to create this let's encrypt certificate with this command i can never get it completed because i get this error here:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p", mail.blabla.cc (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://mail.blabla.cc/.well-known/acme-challenge/JCHNmTQhgr_FDpsERRZUj8caBGFbCbd9t-B3XIaBnHQ: "
```

When i visit regular http for blabla.de i get to the regular website but when i go to http://mail.blabla.de i get just a white page with no error whatsoever. When i direct my browser to the letsencrypt acme challenge i get a 404 not found.

When i visit  https for mail.blabla.de i get to my roundcube installation and can just log in normally (still got a working certificate but i need to make new ones)
These are my apache configs:

For the mail subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /opt/www/roundcubemail/
    ServerName blabla.cc
    ServerAlias mail.blabla.cc
    Alias / "/opt/www/roundcubemail/"

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/opt/www/roundcubemail/">
         Require all granted
         Options -Indexes
         AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AE$
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
           SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blabla.cc/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blabla.cc/privkey.pem
```

For the regular subdomains and main domain:

Port  80:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName blabla.cc

    ServerAdmin simon@blabla.cc
    ServerAlias www.blabla.cc ftp.blabla.cc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webspaces/blabla.cc/htdocs


    <Directory /var/www/webspaces/blabla.cc/htdocs>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            AllowOverride All
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    LogLevel debug

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

Port 443:

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName blabla.cc
        ServerAlias www.blabla.cc ftp.blabla.cc
        ServerAdmin simon@blabla.cc
        DocumentRoot /var/www/webspaces/blabla.cc/htdocs


        <Directory /var/www/webspaces/blabla.cc/htdocs>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                RewriteEngine On
                AllowOverride All
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        LogLevel debug

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blabla.cc/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blabla.cc/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I renamed my domain in this example to blabla.cc.

I don't know why i get the error, can someone please help me with fixing this? I think it's a apache misconfiguration. ...

Comment: I do now. Thought it's obvious ^^

Comment: A 404 error means "file not found", in other words, your server failed to respond to a request for http://mail.blabla.cc/.well-known/acme-challenge/JCHNmTQhgr_FDpsERRZUj8caBGFbCbd9t-B3XIaBnHQ:.  The http://mail.blabla.cc/ part of that is handled by DNS and your apache config, the rest is you running the certbot script in thhe right place.

Comment: Can you show us how do you use the letsencrypt bot ?